# Unable to receive JSON data from url using javascript in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, wcf

Here is the HTML that contains javascript snippet in it:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JSON</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js">
</script>

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("testButton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
           url: "http://localhost:4148/EIS.svc/getShipment/arun/arun",
           success: function (data) {
               obj = eval('(' + data + ')');
               alert(obj);
               var innerHtml = "";
               document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=obj;
                      //'test' is ID of <label1>
               document.getElementById('testlab').innerHTML=obj.shipmentDetails[0].Name;
                     //'testlab' is ID of <label2>
               $("#test").html(innerHtml);
               alert("JSON DATA");
               alert(obj.shipmentDetails[0].Number);
               },
               error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                alert("Error while retrieval – " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText+":"+textStatus+":"+errorThrown);

                }

             });
         });
      });


</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="testButton" value="GET JSON"/>
<label id="test"></label>
<label id="testlab"></label>
</body>
</html>
```

The JSON data returned by the WCF service URL in the browser is as follows:

```
{"shipmentDetails":[{"Name":"AAA","Number":"123"},{"Name":"BBB","Number":"321"}]}
```

When I was clicked the button there was no response in the browser and no errors shown in firebug.

Please help me out where I am making mistake.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your local server also running on port 4148 or are you sure that the `arun` process is returning JSONP data?

Answer (score 1):

When using JSONP, the returned data should be wrapped in a callback function, like so:

```
myCallback({"shipmentDetails":[{"Name":"AAA","Number":"123"},{"Name":"BBB","Number":"321"}]})
```

Also, add the name of the callback to the jQuery ajax definition:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
   url: "http://localhost:4148/EIS.svc/getShipment/arun/arun",
   [...]
   jsonpCallback: 'myCallback'
});
```

Comment: thank you @Borre.. can you please help me how to wrap the returned data in a callback function..

Comment: This should happen in the serverside code, similar to the first code block in my answer

Comment: can you please help me for the above task.

Comment: I have finished the task for wrapping the returned data in the callback function.